# Polly weird behavior (infinite loop?)

Tags: c#, infinite, .net-4.8, polly, circuit-breaker

I'm using `CircuitBreaker` with Polly the first time and I'm facing a problem:

My program executes everything without throwing an Error.
As soon as I get to this codeline, the program Executes it and nothing happens. I cant debug any further. The program is executing this method for ever without a timeout:

```
var cB = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
                .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                (ex, t) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Circuit broken!");
                },
                () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Circuit Reset!");
                });

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var response = await cB.ExecuteAsync((ct) => // <--- Executing this line of code lasts forever
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(
                    endPoint
                ));
                return client.SendAsync(request, ct);
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
```

This is a .NET Framework 4.8 Project.

I created a new Project. Also a .NET Framework 4.8 Project and copy-pasted the code in the picture
into the new project.
And: It runs fine!!

So I suggest, there is a configuration? or an adjustment? in the Project I'm working in, which isn't allowing Polly to work correctly.

But what can it be? I get no feedback by e.g. an error...

Does somebody know what can interact with Polly like that?

Comment: How does your `cB` definition look like? (Please do not share code as image)

Comment: I think you don't understand how does circuit breaker work. If the downstream system is temporarily unaccessible then it will shortcut the request but it will not throw any exception by itself, since it will just increment the successive failure counter. It will rethrow the original exception, which was thrown by the decorated code. CB itself will throw `BrokenCircuitException` only if you try to issue a new request while the CB is in Open state.

Comment: @PeterCsala I understand the functionality of CB. This is a MVC Web Programm. As soon as the mentioned Line of Code is executed, i cant debug any further, no Exception is thrown and the Website is loading. A new clean Project with the SAME Lines of Code executes every line of Code without Problems in ~1s. The endpoint is 100% available. So the Problem isnt the Code i wrote - its something about the Project itself

Comment: @Pregi Well, if the problem is not reproducible in a clean project then we could not really help here.

Comment: Have you tried to call the `ExecuteAsync` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`? It was quite long time ago when I used .NET Framework but if the execution get stuck at an `await`ed command then most probably you have a deadlock.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks for the hint. Gonna try it tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: Let us know if it helped or not

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Yes it did! Ty so much. Still clueless why this is happening...

Comment: @pregi Would you be so kind and mark my post as the answer if it helped you understand why `ConfiguraAwait(false)` solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The observed behaviour was that the application did not make any progress and get stuck at the `await ExecuteAsync` line. Without knowing what the `ExecuteAsync` does people can suspect:

- either we have an infinite loop
- or we have a deadlock

Since the [Circuit Breaker implementation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerEngine.cs) (so called `Engine`) does not perform any kind of things that can cause infinite loop that's why we can exclude that as a possible root cause.

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
breakerController.OnActionPreExecute();

try
{
    TResult result = action(context, cancellationToken);
    if (shouldHandleResultPredicates.AnyMatch(result))
    {
        breakerController.OnActionFailure(new DelegateResult<TResult>(result), context);
    }
    else
    {
        breakerController.OnActionSuccess(context);
    }

    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Exception handledException = shouldHandleExceptionPredicates.FirstMatchOrDefault(ex);
    if (handledException == null)
    {
        throw;
    }

    breakerController.OnActionFailure(new DelegateResult<TResult>(handledException), context);

    if (handledException != ex)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(handledException).Throw();
    }
    throw;
}
```

So the deadlock has remained as our primary suspect. Back in the old days the ASP.NET MVC was using `SynchronizationContext`. [As Stephen Clearly describe it in detail](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) it was used to continue the operation on the same thread as the invoker of the async method.

In other words the awaiter and the awaitee are waiting for each other. The caller thread waits for the `ExecuteAsync` to finish and the `ExecuteAsync` waits for the caller thread to continue.

With the `ConfigureAwait(false)` you are basically [stating](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) that please do not capture the `SynchronizationContext`, so the `ExecuteAsync` can continued on any thread it should not be the caller thread.

In case of ASP.NET Core we don't have to worry about this because the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` :)